# How should we tag Google Play?

Tags: discussion, tags

Ignoring for the moment that "Google Play" is a stupid name, how should we tag it?

Obviously we need to have [google-play](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play) as a synonym of [market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market) (which I have done), but should the new name be the master?  We should probably also take a look at questions tagged the latter than aren't about the Android Market specifically, since the tag may have been seen as generic unlike its other synonym [android-market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-market).

Comment: google-play probably needs to replace the market tag. However, Google-play also includes Play Movies, Play Music, etc. etc.

Comment: Good point.  We'll need `play-music` synonymized with `google-music` and so on.

Comment: We may also want a `play-store` synonym since that's how the app identifies itself.

Comment: I think we should :)

Comment: Aah Google, Y u no think about poor moderators when you change fancy names!! B)

Comment: ***If*** `market` is going to be replaced, it should be replaced with `google-play-store`. Similarly: `google-music` to `google-play-music`, `google-books` to `google-play-books`, etc. I'm still not convinced that we should, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that we should rush to make synonyms. After all, all those pre-March-2011 questions are about the Market, *not* Google Play. Further, Google Play is not yet available globally.

I think, instead, that there should be a clear delineation between the tags before and after the launch of Google Play. Of course, the wikis and excerpts for each tag should clearly explain the difference.

In much the same way questions about Eclair or Froyo don't apply to Ice Cream Sandwich and vice versa, so also to old questions about Market, Google Music, et al., don't apply to their new Google Play counterparts.

Comment: Is there really a substantial difference?  More so than between versions 2 and 3 of the Market, for example?

Comment: Not so far. Enforcing a synonym is going to make questions about the market from '10 and '11 seem really weird. We're all about the future readers, remember?

Comment: If they didn't change the name that would still hold true, which is why I mentioned the Market versions.  If questions become too localized we can close them, answers can be updated.  I don't think having them as separate tags will do anything apart from create work short-term watching for when people use the wrong tag and correcting it.

Answer (score -1):

I think, a master tag `play-store` should be created (if it doesn't already exist). `market`, `android-market` & `google-play` tags deserve to be synonym of `play-store`.

Comment: No, that won't work. Google Play is the "umbrella" name.

Comment: K.. then, ignore google-play from answer.